# wcf rest starter kit preview 2 error: requires VS 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, rest

I'm trying to install the WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2, but that fails with the message that I need Visual Studio 2008 SP1, which I actually do have installed:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks, regards, Miel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Visual Studio installed without SP1 (Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM is not SP1), but you have .NET 3.5 SP1. The dialog box has confused you. [Download VS.NET 2008 SP1 from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en).

VS.NET 2008 SP1 != .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: It confused me indeed. Thanks for providing the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 **RTM**